# Elasticsearch, why "SELECT * FROM my_index LIMIT 1" takes so long?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-performance

I've a decently sized ES index (10TB) with 50 split on 50 machines (1 shard each), close to 10B rows. Machines are top-tier (the largest you can get on AWS). RAM per ES instance is set to 30 GB.

Whenever I run a very simple query such as :

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

It takes between 2 to 20+ seconds (I even got 502):

Response

```
{
  "took" : 17584,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 50,
    "successful" : 50,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
```

Is there a way to make it faster? I noticed that the LIMIT clause is not working great in ElasticSearch (or better, I'm probably not using it right)

Comment: Using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is silly. Anyway, it's slow because it's scanning all shards.

Comment: @Dai exactly, I also mentioned this in my answer :) pls hv a look

Comment: @Dai Are you suggesting that an order by would make it quick? This is a sample query, meant to be silly, but there can be similar cases, like in paging.
I don't believe Postgres would need to scan all DBs for this and it is always fast.

Comment: @rodi What is this query meant to accomplish though? Are you just wanting to see if the ES index _contains anything_ - or something else?

Comment: @Dai The goal is: the user might make very generic queries that would match hundreds of millions of results before making queries that will match only a subset. I would like that those queries didn't take long. E.g. You look for "elasticsearch" on google, and then you look "elasticsearch error12345".

Answer (score 1):

Interesting ES performance question, please clarify a few things, and based on my understanding I will try to explain the things

1. When you mentioned **RAM per ES instance is set to 30 GB**, I guess you meant ES heap size is 30 GB, not the ES node's RAM size? as thumb rule is to assign 50% RAM of the node to ES Heap size and it(ES heap) shouldn't cross 32 GB.
2. Hope you have tried this query during peak and non-peak hours and your range is including both the time-frame?

**Now, few recommendations to speed up your search query**

3. **Try to reduce the number of shards for your index,** currently its 50 shards, this means the coordinating node has to collect the search result from 50 nodes(your case of 1 shard each node)and this inter-node communication might be taking quite some time.
4. Have written [short tips to improve search performance](https://opster.com/blogs/improve-elasticsearch-search-performance/), and see if you can apply to your cluster, index

Comment: 1) Yes, heap. RAM is a couple fold higher
2) dev env
3) If I halven it, the storage per node will be higher than 40GB, would that be a good idea? And the usage is subject to grow
4) Thank you!

Comment: @rodi reg 3) its disk storge which will grow and that's fine, please do it, measure it and let us know the gain :)

Comment: Ok, requirements now asked to put 10TB of data in it. reducing the number of nodes would result in >400GB per node. From Elastic guidelines it seems we might even have to add more nodes: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-size-recommendation

Comment: @rodi, i don't understand why you want to keep 10 TB of data in just single index, ideally you should create a new index with few shards, so that you have to search fewer shards, please note my recommendation is to reduce **shards not nodes**

Comment: We need because the data is all of the same kind (same mapping), so I would imagine it should stay in the same index; breaking it in multiple indexes would mean partitioning the data

Comment: @rodi could you please provide update on my last comment